# Not sure how to create a default constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm having trouble creating a parameterless default constructor for this class I am writing. The constructor should go into:

```
public Track(){

    }
```

The following code is the entire class I'm working on, I've tried using the returned values from the below methods and setting them to 0 but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package comp125;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Track {

        //removed max entries (was 1000, now has no limit)

        ArrayList<Waypoint> pointList = new ArrayList<Waypoint>();{
                //for (int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++){
                        //System.out.println(pointList.get(i));
                //}
        }
        Scanner scanner;
        String fileMain;


        public Track(String filename) throws IOException, GPSException {

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));



                scanner.hasNextLine();

                while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {



                        String line = scanner.nextLine();

                        pointList.add(new Waypoint(line));



                }

                File f = new File(filename);                            //easy filenotfound exception
                if(!f.exists()){
                        throw new IOException();  
                }

                fileMain = filename;




        }

        //This is where we create an empty track
        public Track(){




        }

        public int size() {

                return pointList.size();

        }

        public void add(Waypoint wp) {


                pointList.add(pointList.size(), wp);


        }

        public String getFilename() {

                return fileMain;


        }

        public String getTimestamp() {


                return pointList.get(0).getTimestamp();
        }

        public double getDistance() {

                double totDist = 0.0;

                for (int i = 1; i < pointList.size(); i++)
                {

                        totDist = totDist + pointList.get(i-1).distanceTo(pointList.get(i));

                }

                //System.out.println(totDist);
                return totDist;




        }


        public double getElevationGain() {
                double elevGain = 0.0;


                for(int i = 1; i < pointList.size(); i++){
                        if(pointList.get(i).getElevation() > pointList.get(i-1).getElevation() ){
                                elevGain = elevGain + Math.abs(pointList.get(i).getElevation() - pointList.get(i-1).getElevation());
                        }
                }


                return elevGain;
        }


        public String toString() {

                String str1 = this.getFilename();
                String str2 = this.getTimestamp();
                String str3 = String.valueOf(this.getDistance());
                String str4 = String.valueOf(this.getElevationGain());
                //System.out.println(str1);
                //System.out.println(str2);
                //System.out.println(str3);

                return str1 + str2 + str3 + str4;

        }


        public Waypoint closestTo(Waypoint wp) {

                Waypoint returnValue = pointList.get(0);
                for(int i = 1; i < pointList.size(); i++){
                        if(pointList.get(i).distanceTo(wp) < returnValue.distanceTo(wp)){
                                returnValue = pointList.get(i);
                        }
                }

                return returnValue;



        }
}
```

Comment: `but that doesn't seem to work` what didn't work exactly.

Comment: I basically wasn't getting a working constructor, should've been more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what to put into the parameter-less constructor, you have two options :

Keep it empty - all the properties will be initialized to their default values

```
public Track() 
{
}
```

Use some default value instead of `filename`, and use it to initialize the instance the same way you do in your other constructor `Track(String filename)`. You can even call one constructor from the other :

```
public Track() throws IOException, GPSException
{
    this("DEFAULT_FILE_NAME"); 
}
```

If you require a parameter-less constructor throwing no exceptions, you can catch the exceptions thrown from the other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is you're attempting to use the class, but there is no data.

You can create fake (mock) data like so:

```
public Track(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        pointList.add(new Waypoint(/* put the data here that you need for the Waypoint constructor */);
    }
}
```

But your comment `//This is where we create an empty track` on the constructor seems appropriate...there aren't any tracks =)